# Access restrictions using cocoa pods and FeedKit?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, watchos

I have an RSS Reader running on iOS(11.2.6) and watchOS(4.2) using cocoa pods and FeedKit:

https://github.com/nmdias/FeedKit

Result: The simulated version runs fine, RSS feeds get displayed on watch as expected. But the installed version fails to read valid RSS feeds on the real Apple watch.
This is the console output, to my surprise showing access restrictions (Operation not permitted):

```
2018-03-12 12:04:39.291680+0100 RssReader WatchKit Extension[425:996313] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed path:/var/run/mDNSResponder Socket:8 Err:-1 Errno:1 Operation not permitted
```

Do I need to configure cocoa pods in a similar way we've seen with 'Sandbox' and if yes, where can I find configuration files?

If of help, please find the complete console output as follows:

```
Session activated: 2
2018-03-12 12:04:36.279959+0100 RssReader WatchKit Extension[425:996313] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 1
2018-03-12 12:04:37.284300+0100 RssReader WatchKit Extension[425:996313] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 2
2018-03-12 12:04:38.287957+0100 RssReader WatchKit Extension[425:996313] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 3
2018-03-12 12:04:39.291680+0100 RssReader WatchKit Extension[425:996313] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed path:/var/run/mDNSResponder Socket:8 Err:-1 Errno:1 Operation not permitted
2018-03-12 12:04:39.303812+0100 RssReader WatchKit Extension[425:996313] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: ServiceNotRunning(-65563)
2018-03-12 12:04:39.327295+0100 RssReader WatchKit Extension[425:996313] TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x17665b90]: 10:-72000 Err(-65563)
2018-03-12 12:04:39.442468+0100 RssReader WatchKit Extension[425:996348] Task . HTTP load failed (error code: -1009 [10:-72000])
2018-03-12 12:04:39.443905+0100 RssReader WatchKit Extension[425:996313] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1009
Error Domain=com.feedkit.error Code=-1000 "Feed not found" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Couldn't parse any known feed from the provided DOM structure, NSLocalizedDescription=Feed not found, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Provide a valid Atom/RSS DOM structure }
2018-03-12 12:06:19.555212+0100 RssReader WatchKit Extension[425:996503] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 1
2018-03-12 12:06:20.560959+0100 RssReader WatchKit Extension[425:996503] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 2
2018-03-12 12:06:21.566365+0100 RssReader WatchKit Extension[425:996503] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 3
2018-03-12 12:06:22.568004+0100 RssReader WatchKit Extension[425:996503] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed path:/var/run/mDNSResponder Socket:8 Err:-1 Errno:1 Operation not permitted
2018-03-12 12:06:22.568429+0100 RssReader WatchKit Extension[425:996503] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: ServiceNotRunning(-65563)
2018-03-12 12:06:22.570456+0100 RssReader WatchKit Extension[425:996503] TIC TCP Conn Failed [2:0x17572660]: 10:-72000 Err(-65563)
2018-03-12 12:06:22.598663+0100 RssReader WatchKit Extension[425:996503] Task . HTTP load failed (error code: -1009 [10:-72000])
2018-03-12 12:06:22.599387+0100 RssReader WatchKit Extension[425:996503] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1009
Error Domain=com.feedkit.error Code=-1000 "Feed not found" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Couldn't parse any known feed from the provided DOM structure, NSLocalizedDescription=Feed not found, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Provide a valid Atom/RSS DOM structure }
2018-03-12 12:15:14.556397+0100 RssReader WatchKit Extension[425:996729] [WC] -[WCXPCManager onqueue_reconnect]_block_invoke error reconnecting to daemon due to NSXPCConnectionInterrupted
sessionReachabilityDidChange: falseRssReader
```

Comment: Has anyone found an answer to this?  I'm running into a similar issue attempting to use FeedKit on watchos 6. It's failing with the message "NSError domain: "NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 256" as it attempts to read data from the supplied URL via Data(contentsOf: url) within the FeedKit's FeedParser.